# Trying to render a barcode image, but object is not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, barcode

I am trying to set up a code which creates tickets by generating images of barcodes, from a txt file, and pasting that on the ticket image.

```
import barcode
import time
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
mylist = []
with open('/Users/Droid/Desktop/my_project/Tickets/Tnumfile.TXT', 'r') as f:
for line in f.readlines():    #Walks through each line
    code = barcode.get('code', line, writer=ImageWriter()) 
    filename = code.save(line.strip())        #Saves Line 'tnumfile' as filename
    mylist.insert(0,line.strip() + '.png')



time.sleep(2)
from PIL import Image

for item in mylist:

im1 = Image.open('/Users/Droid/Desktop/my_project/Ticket.png') 
im2 = Image.open('/Users/Droid/Desktop/my_project/Tickets' + item) 
area = (30, 1380, 553, 1660)                                       

im1.paste(im2, area)
im1.save('line' + item)
```

supposed to run through .txt file converting all the barcodes to images and copying them onto the ticket image template, instead keeps telling me:

```
  File "C:\Users\Droid\Desktop\my_project\Script.py", line 7, in <module>
    code = barcode.get('code', line, writer=ImageWriter())  
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 14):

The [`python-barcode` project](https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/) requires Pillow to be installed if you want to render barcodes to an image, otherwise it sets `ImageWriter` to `None`. See the [`barcode.writer` source code](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/blob/master/barcode/writer.py) for details (PIL is the name of the package that Pillow provides).

Run `pip install Pillow` to remedy this.

You can also tell pip to pull in dependencies by installing the `python-barcode` `images` extras:

```
pip install python-barcode[images]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this installation:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```